# My website folders are owned by me, not www-data, how to recursively change to www-data user and group?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am getting a 403 forbidden when trying to view a rails website, and I am guessing this is a permissions issue.

All the files and folders are owned by the user I logged into the computer with, and from what I understand Nginx runs under the www-data account.

How can I recursively update all files/folders to use the www-data account (and group correct?).

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**chown**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) - if your data is stored in, for example, /var/www then

```
cd /var
chown -R www-data:www-data www
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I recommend against getting used to using directory names relative to the current working directory when there are good options.  E.g. 'chown .... /var/www' instead.  This can save you some trouble if you get in the habit (e.g. 'cd / home/user ; rm *` instead of 'rm / home/user/*'